# Python project - Access a file from parent or above directory

Tags: python, module, python-import, importerror

I have a python project of the following structure:

```
ai_project\
    project\
        project_3\
            Functionality_1.pnyb --> "Imports project_helper and project_tests"
            helper.py --> Content of file: "../../helper.py"
            project_helper.py --> "Imports helper"
            tests.py --> Content of file: "../../tests.py"
            project_tests.py --> Imports tests.py
        project_4\
        project_5\
    data\
    some_folder_name\
    helper.py --> Some reusable helper methods
    requirments.py
    tests.py --> Content of file : Some reusable test methods
```

I see that the code in functionaly_1 is trying to access or inherit the test.py and the helper.py from parent class. But while executing the code I get an Syntax error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\udacity\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-1-504bb0e8ad18>", line 3, in <module>
    import helper

  File "D:\CodingWorkspace\JupyterWorkspace\ai_project\project\project_3\helper.py", line 1
    ../../helper.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I fix this? I can copy paste the tests and helper file to each functionality folder, but that defeats the purpose.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, the code snippet is very unreadable. Please spend sometime in formatting the snippet so that's it is easy to understand.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: put code and error without `<br>`

Comment: Traceback from error posted and the formatting is better now.